# Verify if array is orthogonal

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, error-correcting-codes

[Orthogonal arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_array) often appear in probabilistic algorithms. They can be efficiently constructed from, e.g., [BCH codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code).
But is there an efficient algorithm that can verify if an array is orthogonal? I would be particularly curious about the strength-4 *binary* arrays.

In my last edit I added that the array is binary. It seems to me it can help.